# GCC produces unneccessary register pushes for simple ISR on AVR

Tags: c++, avr

I have some simple C++ programm that produces the following assembler text if compile with g++. The only statement is `sbi`, which doesn't affect any status flags. I wonder why G++ produces these useless push/pop's of `r0` and `r1`?

```
.global __vector_14
        .type   __vector_14, @function
__vector_14:
        push r1  ; 
        push r0  ; 
        in r0,__SREG__   ; ,
        push r0  ; 
        clr __zero_reg__         ; 
/* prologue: Signal */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 3 */
.L__stack_usage = 3
        sbi 0x1e,0       ; ,
/* epilogue start */
        pop r0   ; 
        out __SREG__,r0  ; ,
        pop r0   ; 
        pop r1   ; 
        reti
        .size   __vector_14, .-__vector_14
```

Is there any way that g++ automatically omits these register saves. I don't want to declare the ISR as `ISR_NAKED` in general.

Edit:
This is the correcponding C++ code (-Os or -O3):

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

struct AppFlags final {
    bool expired : 1;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main() {
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    auto f = reinterpret_cast<volatile AppFlags*>(0x3e);
    f->expired = true;
}
```

Comment: It'd be really nice if you can provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with _both_ source and assembly code, as well as compilation flags. Did you enable optimizations?

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC generating useless code in ISR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943129/gcc-generating-useless-code-in-isr)

Comment: Not really, this is even more simple and obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20296

> The 
>   difficulty is, that the present architecture of the avr back-end does not 
>   easily permit to improve this case: Every instruction pattern (like "multiply 
>   two 16 bit integers" or "sign-extend a 16 bit variable to 32 bits") presently 
>   is free to assume that may overwrite or change r0 and r1 unless it leaves the 
>   "**zero_reg**" with 0 after finishing it's task.
>
> Resolving this issue, IMHO, would require a major refactoring of the 
>   back-end.

This is a long standing bug / enhancement request to avr-backend.

Comment: There was some activity on the ticket after you posted your answer. Apparently there is a fix now.

Comment: Issue was resolved in 2017, i.e. GCC 8 and later (in combination with not too old binutils) now generate minimal ISR prologues/epilogues. NB: as of 2022, Arduino/platformio still use GCC 7.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you are using an outdated compiler.  The [mentioned optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81268) has been added in v8 (released spring 2018), see [GCC v8 Release Notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html#avr):

> The compiler now generates efficient interrupt service routine (ISR) prologues and epilogues. This is achieved by using the new [AVR pseudo instruction](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.29/as/AVR-Pseudo-Instructions.html) __gcc_isr which is supported and resolved by the GNU assembler.

Comment: The question was from 06/2017

Comment: Yes.  And the question is very common and has been asked more than once.  While you usually only find replies that explain why the code is NOT as efficient as expected, the answer explains what to do in order to get code that IS as efficient as expected.

Comment: I plus one this, because an answer regarding some more modern available technology is useful. Have you tried using a newer gcc version with Atmel sutdio 7?

Comment: Newer more detailed answer from the same user on a near-duplicate: [Atmel studio (GCC) uses a lot of instructions even in an empty ISR function? Can that be optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67630879) - explains in detail what the new compiler / assembler feature is about.

Answer (score 2):

GCC before version 8 doesn't optimize ISR prologues and epilogues.
[GCC 8 and later](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html#avr) now emit `__gcc_isr` [pseudo-instructions](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AVR-Pseudo-Instructions.html) that enclose your ISR body when compiling with some optimization levels such as `-Os` or when supplying `-mgas-isr-prologues`.

The GNU assembler (from not too outdated binutils versions) understands these pseudo-instructions and [scans the instructions](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=10232) ([via](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21683)) between `__gcc_isr 1` and `__gcc_isr 2` to decide which of r0 (tmp register), r1 (zero register), SREG (status register) need to be saved and restored.

Thus, for your example I get a pretty minimal objdump (when compiling with GCC 11.1):

```
$ avr-objdump -d foo.o
[..]
00000000 <__vector_14>:
   0:   f0 9a           sbi 0x1e, 0 ; 30
   2:   18 95           reti
[..]
```

When I tell GCC to just emit assembly we see the pseudo-instructions:

```
$ avr-g++ -c -S -Os -mmcu=atmega328p  foo.c -fno-exceptions
$ cat foo.s
[..]
.global __vector_14
    .type   __vector_14, @function
__vector_14:
    __gcc_isr 1
/* prologue: Signal */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0...3 */
.L__stack_usage = 0 + __gcc_isr.n_pushed
    sbi 0x1e,0
/* epilogue start */
    __gcc_isr 2
    reti
    __gcc_isr 0,r0
[..]
```

Answer (score 1):

GCC pushes all used registers.  Your only real recourse is to enable the `naked` attribute, which will only push the stack pointer.  Or change to assembly language.

Comment: The whole contents of the ISR is `sbi 0x1e,0`. So no registers are needed. The compiler should be aware of that.

Comment: Perhaps, but gcc is what it is.  If the ISR is that simple, perhaps just a quick inline assembly call to the ISR without all the stack stuff...  or naked mode if you're not comfortable in inline assembly.

Comment: Switching to `ISR_NAKED` is too dangerous, if I change the ISR-Code later on. The compiler is aware to use `sbi` instructions in this case (register below 0x32 an single bit set). So, why isn't the compile aware that this instruction doesn't modify any status flags in SREG?

Comment: @wimalopaan: these pushes and pops are part of function's prologue and epilogue. Compiler will always produce it. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I have  no idea but this is an old topic in the dedicated AVR forums, many users of which use GCC.  I didn't contribute to GCC so can't address the question of why it is what it is.

Comment: @wimalopaan  You're welcome to write a smarter compiler if you can.  Or contribute to gcc project and show the world how to do it better.  It is open source, feel free.