# Atmel studio (GCC) uses a lot of instructions even in an empty ISR function? Can that be optimized?

Tags: assembly, gcc, avr, interrupt-handling, atmelstudio

ISRs take a long time, so I looked at the asm to see what it was doing.

I compile this C with `gcc -O3 -mmcu=attiny13a` and some other options.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
ISR(TIM0_COMPA_vect)
{

}
```

`avr-objdump.exe -d test.elf` output:

```
00000048 <__vector_6>:
  48:   1f 92           push    r1
  4a:   0f 92           push    r0
  4c:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  4e:   0f 92           push    r0
  50:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  52:   0f 90           pop r0
  54:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
  56:   0f 90           pop r0
  58:   1f 90           pop r1
  5a:   18 95           reti
```

Is the assembler code right, although C code is empty?

These links explain some about `ISR()`, but don't go into detail about which parts of the asm are required, or if it would be possible to get GCC to optimize away some of the instructions in simple ISRs that don't need them.

- https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html `ISR()` macro
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Function-Attributes.html  some details about `__attribute__((interrupt))`.

---

GCC's asm output (https://godbolt.org/z/zzbY5KE3c) uses pseudo-instructions like `__gcc_isr 1`.

Newer GCC (9.2 on Godbolt) supports `-mno-gas-isr-prologues` to get GCC to show the real instructions that match the disassembly from Atmel Studio above.  So if anyone wants to play with this, something that has an effect in https://godbolt.org/z/q6M518qfP will probably have the same effect in real Atmel Studio.

Comment: What compiler does that IDE use? (google says probably GCC, so I tagged that)  Anyway, is this optimized code?  If not, very likely some of it is unnecessary; just `reti` might be sufficient.  Or maybe not, IDK.  But note that having `r1` as a `__ZERO_REGISTER__` is normal for GCC, but not something an interrupt handler can assume, so that part might also be just a lack of optimization not removing it in a function where it isn't needed.

Comment: The compiler is avr-gcc-5.4.0 of avr8-gnu-toolchain. The compile option is '-03'. Full compile option is [-x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATtiny_DFP\1.3.229\include"  -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -g2 -Wall -mmcu=attiny13a -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATtiny_DFP\1.3.229\gcc\dev\attiny13a" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.o)"] Do I need any otpion for reduce code?

Comment: I tried this on Godbolt (https://godbolt.org/z/Ee61fxKhq), with `-mno-gas-isr-prologues` which I *think* just expands stuff like `__gcc_isr 1` into real instructions in the asm output.  Still, interesting question; I edited in some research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC produces unneccessary register pushes for simple ISR on AVR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493718/gcc-produces-unneccessary-register-pushes-for-simple-isr-on-avr)

Answer (score 1):

> Is the assembler code right, although C code is empty?

Yes.  This is the code for avr-gcc up to and including v7.  Newer versions of the compiler might generate more efficient code, see the [GCC v8 Release Notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html#avr). The reason is this:

### avr-gcc ABI: R0 and R1 Modeling, Usage and Benefits

When the [avr-gcc ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Register_Layout) was devised, the decision was to model R0 and R1 as fixed registers.  *"Fixed register*" means that the compiler won't use them in register allocation or otherwise in any way.  The only use of these regs was in the final stage of compilation when assembly code is printed to `*.s`, where these registers could be used implicitly in the respective output strings.  This is basically the same like instruction output via inline assembly, which is opaque to the compiler.

The reason behind this choice was that overall code quality could be improved by having these extra registers at hand, where R0 is used as a temporary register aka. `__tmp_reg__`, and R1 aka. `__zero_reg__` contains a value of zero. For example, to compare a 16-bit integer in register %0 against 42, you can just

```
cpi %A0, 42
cpc %B0, __zero_reg__
```

without any further ado, i.e. no need to allocate some temporary register, clear it etc.

### Disadvantage of R0 and R1 being Fixed Registers

The disadvantage of this approach is that there is no usage of life info for these registers, for example in multiplication code like

```cpp
char mul (char x)
{
    return x * x * x * x;
}
```

you have to reset R1 to 0 according to the ABI because `MUL` destroys its content:

```lisp
mul:
    mul r24,r24
    mov r24,r0
    clr r1      ; Superfluous
    mul r24,r24 ; Overrides r1
    mov r24,r0
    clr r1      ; Restore __zero_reg__ to 0
    ret
```

The first `clr r1` is superfluous because the following `mul` will override it.

That ABI design lead also to these expensive ISR pro- and epilogues because no analysis is available on whether R0, R1 are used or changed, same for SREG. Therefore, a classic ISR prologue has to

- Save R0, R1 and SREG.
- Set R1 to 0 (because it might temporarily hold a non-0 value like during the mul-sequence from above, but ISR code expects R1=0).

no matter what the body of the ISR is, and the epilogue has to restore them.

### avr-gcc v8+ Solution: Pseudo-instruction __gcc_isr in ISRs

Due to the complexity of the problem, it took 12 years from filing [PR20296](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR20296) to its resolution.  The bulk of analysis was shifted from the compiler to the assembler by means of a pseudo-instruction `__gcc_isr`.  To see how it works, consider the following C code:

```cpp
volatile char c;

__attribute__((__signal__))
void __vector_X (void)
{
    ++c;
}
```

and the assembly code from avr-gcc v8+ `-Os -save-temps`:

```
__vector_X:
    __gcc_isr 1
    lds  r24,c
    subi r24,lo8(-1)
    sts  c,r24
    __gcc_isr 2
    reti
    __gcc_isr 0,r24
```

**What the compiler does:**

- Don't generate `__gcc_isr` if Binutils don't support it (determined during configure whether gas accepts `-mgcc-isr`), if optimization is off, if the ISR is attributed `no_gccisr`, if `-mgas-isr-prologues` has been switched off, etc.
- Don't generate `__gcc_isr` if the ISR has open-coded calls or does weird stuff like non-local goto (setjmp / longjmp).
- If all goes well, print `__gcc_isr` pseudo-instructions instead of actual ISR prologue / epilogues.

**What the assembler does:**

- It analyzes the ocmplete ISR code starting at prologue chunk `__gcc_isr 1` up to final chunk 0 and records usage of R0, R1 and effects on SREG.
- Don't analyze code behind function calls: If `[r]call` is encountered, assume the worst for R0, R1 and SREG. Tail-calls (calls via some jump instruction) have already been handled by the compiler.
- Print optimized prologue for chunk 1 and epilogue(s) for chunk(s) 2 according to R0, R1, SREG usage. The register specified with chunk 0 may be used to push / pop SREG because the compiler uses this register anyways.

For the example from above, the final code will be:

```
<__vector_X>:
    8f 93           push r24
    8f b7           in   r24, 0x3f  ; SREG
    8f 93           push r24
    80 91 60 00     lds  r24, 0x0060    ; <c>
    8f 5f           subi r24, 0xFF
    80 93 60 00     sts  0x0060, r24    ;  <c>
    8f 91           pop r24
    8f bf           out 0x3f, r24   ; SREG
    8f 91           pop r24
    18 95           reti
```

The obvious advantage of letting the assembler doing the analysis is that it even works for code from inline assembly which is opaque to GCC.

---

### "Does inline asm matter?": A Note on Inline Assembly

The first thing to notice is that we get analysis of inline asm for free with the current approach. Handling of inline asm was not the reason behind the decision to let gas do the work, though, it's just a nice side effect. So what follows is basically a TL;DR why we use gas as a working horse.

It's correct that inline asm must make all side effects explicit, with a grain of salt:

Before the cc0→CCmode [transition](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR92729), there was no condition code register to clobber, so the assumption would be that basically each and ever insn would clobber cc0.  The situation didn't change much with the introduction of CCmode (it actually got worse):  Compare insns are setting CC, but almost every other insn besides branches or super-simple 1-instruction isns are clobbering CC.

The reason is that many insns have very complex insn output printers, for example for specific arithmetic or multi-byte load / stores.  It's not possible with any reasonable amount of work to model exact CC behavior on that level, hence just assume CC clobber.  This also applies to inline asm: Since advent of CCmode, the avr backend just adds "cc" clobbers to *all inline assembly* so that legacy code won't break, see [avr.cc](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/avr/avr.cc;h=4ed390e4cf9ec39c97c2dc67da48defa5dcf4f3e;hb=HEAD#l14491).

Similar situation for tmp_reg:  Insn printers will use it implicitly, then and when, so the compiler cannot work out its usage / clobber status with any reasonable precision even *if it was* an ordinary, allocated register and not a fixed one.

Same for zero_reg, which is also fixed.  Some insn printers will just use it in special cases, and it's not possible to model this in a reasonable way, either.  As you already noticed, insns (and inline asm) may assume zero_reg = 0, which is the reason why ISR functions with a single

```cpp
asm ("sts 0,__zero_reg__");
```

will work and instanciate zero_reg magically.

And of course, it's not possible to add implicit operands like `"r" (0)` to inline asm — even if it was possible, this would break existing code.  And clobbering R0 or R1 is still void because they are fixed, so we don't want to rely on clobbers being present.
And technically, an inline asm that's clobbering zero_reg and then restores it to 0, does not clobber it.  However, ISRs would still need to know.

Comment: Does inline asm matter?  It needs clobbers or output operands if it wants to write any registers or condition codes, otherwise it's undefined behaviour.  I guess it matters for reading `r1`, though; GNU C Extended asm could normally hard-code it instead of using `"r"((char)0)` I guess.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Too long for a comment, see "A Note on Inline Assembly" in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for adding that section; I'm loosely familiar with some GCC internals, enough for the concept of an "instruction printer" to make sense, and thus grok that those are recipes that GCC doesn't look into. And that GCC wouldn't track an R0 clobber. Fun fact: the x86 back-end also has an implicit `"cc"` clobber, for the same reason that most instructions clobber it, and the likely benefit is a lot smaller than amount of breakage from existing sloppy code.

Comment: Oh right, and if inline asm inside an ISR modifies R1 and re-zeroes it before leaving, the ISR needs to save/restore R1 *in case it's interrupting something else that was in the middle of using R1 for something non-zero*.  So it's not just asm depending on reading a zero that might matter.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Yes, that's the complication with R1.  And insns at the asm out stage are basically like inlineT asm: They have operands, constraints and an asm template string.  But they also have RTL code that describes the insn's semantics. They may have more than one constraint alternative, and in comlpex cases you may use C++ code with many different case for just one insn.  An easy example is [SP = reg](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/avr/avr.md;h=efae7efb69b103bfe69706badb8d46c7c58a6060;hb=HEAD#l782) that uses R0 just in 1 of 5 alternatives.